# Generator of a Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes

For a (index-)homogeneous Markov process $X_t$, its infinitesimal generator A is defined to act on suitable functions $f : \mathbb R^n → \mathbb R$ by
$$
    A f (x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbf{E}^{x} [f(X_{t})] - f(x)}{t}. 
$$

1. In the case of a inhomogeneous Markov process, how is its generator
   defined?
2. How can we go from the generator of a (inhomogeneous or homogeneous)
   Markov process to the Markov process (or its transition
   kernels/probabilities)?

   There are two steps here, if I am correct:

   - first go from the generator to the one-parameter semigroup of operators defined [by the cauchy problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/355045/1281), and
   - secondly go from the semigroup of operators to the transition kernels, by letting the integrand to be the indicator function of a measurable subset.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: As far as I'm concerned the generator doesn't make (great) sense in the inhomogeneous case. In the non-homogeneous case there is no transition semigroup, just a two-parameter Markovian family:
$$ P^{s,t} f(x) = E(f(X_t) \, |  \, X_s = x)$$
When the process is homogeneous the above family only depends on the difference $s-t$ and you write
$$ P^{s,t} f(x) = E(f(X_t) \, |  \, X_s = x) = E(f(X_{t-s} \, | \, X_0 = x)) = E^x(f(X_{t-s}))$$

Comment: The generator $A$ makes sense in the homogeneous case since it generates the semigroup of transition probabilities (at least for a suitable subfamily of functions $f$):
$$ E^x[f(X_t)] = P^t f(x)=  f(x) + Af(x) + o(t) $$
If there is a generalization, it will would be something like:
$$ A(s)f(x) = \lim_{t \to s} \frac{E(f(X_t) \, |  \, X_s = x) - f(x)}{t-s} $$
But I don't know if this object can be exploited as well as the generator in the homogeneous case.

Comment: @Bunder: Thanks! In $E^x[f(X_t)] = P^t f(x)=  f(x) + Af(x) + o(t)$, do you miss a $t$ that multiplies $Af(x)$? I.e. do you mean $E^x[f(X_t)] = P^t f(x)=  f(x) + [Af(x)]\, t + o(t)$ instead?

Comment: indeed :). I can't correct it though.

Comment: @Bunder:Thanks! Regarding the second part of my post, are the two steps correct for going from the generator of a (inhomogeneous or homogeneous) Markov process to the Markov process (or its transition kernels/probabilities)?